# ContentResolver().update doesn't work

Tags: android, sql-update

I'm new to android programming. I tried to update a task in my database with the ContentResolver. But instead of updating and/or showing the toast message, the app seems to process for a while (screen is white for a few seconds) and the item remains the same.
Other operations on ContentResolver works (e.g. inserting)
I tried to debug, but I can't find an error in the debugging window. Obviously all values and Uri seems to be correct... Error must be in following line:

```
int rowsAffected = getContentResolver().update(mCurrentTaskUri, values, null, null);

           if (rowsAffected == 0) {

                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.aufgabe_bearbeiten_fehlgeschlagen), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.aufgabe_bearbeiten_erfolgreich), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
```

Comment: this code is use in Fragment or Activity ?

Comment: In an Activity.